# How to ignore these informations

Tags: apt, cuda

I want to install CUDA with the following commands given by [NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

I just type the first and second command and later I installed CUDA with another methods.

And now I want to install `python3-tk`, however it return the following results

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-tk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-cublas-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-cublas-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
 cuda-cudart-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-cudart-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
 cuda-cufft-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-cufft-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
 cuda-curand-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-curand-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
 cuda-cusolver-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-cusolver-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
 cuda-cusparse-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-cusparse-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
 cuda-npp-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-npp-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
 cuda-nvgraph-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-nvgraph-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
 cuda-nvrtc-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-nvrtc-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
 cuda-runtime-8-0 : Depends: cuda-nvrtc-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-nvgraph-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-cusolver-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-cublas-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-cufft-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-curand-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-cusparse-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-npp-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-cudart-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
 cuda-toolkit-8-0 : Depends: cuda-nvml-dev-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-driver-dev-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.44-1 is to be installed
 python3-tk : Depends: blt (>= 2.4z-7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How to ignore the information of CUDA since I have successfully installed CUDA. It's annoying!

And the output of  `apt-get -f install`

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cuda-8-0 cuda-command-line-tools-8-0 cuda-core-8-0 cuda-cublas-8-0
  cuda-cublas-dev-8-0 cuda-cudart-8-0 cuda-cudart-dev-8-0 cuda-cufft-8-0
  cuda-cufft-dev-8-0 cuda-curand-8-0 cuda-curand-dev-8-0 cuda-cusolver-8-0
  cuda-cusolver-dev-8-0 cuda-cusparse-8-0 cuda-cusparse-dev-8-0
  cuda-demo-suite-8-0 cuda-documentation-8-0 cuda-driver-dev-8-0
  cuda-license-8-0 cuda-misc-headers-8-0 cuda-npp-8-0 cuda-npp-dev-8-0
  cuda-nvgraph-8-0 cuda-nvgraph-dev-8-0 cuda-nvml-dev-8-0 cuda-nvrtc-8-0
  cuda-nvrtc-dev-8-0 cuda-runtime-8-0 cuda-samples-8-0 cuda-toolkit-8-0
  cuda-visual-tools-8-0 fonts-dejavu-extra freeglut3-dev libbonobo2-0
  libbonobo2-common libcuda1-367 libgconf2-4 libgif4 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin
  libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libidl-common libidl0
  liborbit-2-0 liborbit2 libsctp1 lksctp-tools nvidia-367-dev
  nvidia-opencl-icd-367 tzdata-java
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cuda-cublas-8-0 cuda-cudart-8-0 cuda-cufft-8-0 cuda-curand-8-0
  cuda-cusolver-8-0 cuda-cusparse-8-0 cuda-driver-dev-8-0 cuda-npp-8-0
  cuda-nvgraph-8-0 cuda-nvml-dev-8-0 cuda-nvrtc-8-0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cuda-cublas-8-0 cuda-cudart-8-0 cuda-cufft-8-0 cuda-curand-8-0
  cuda-cusolver-8-0 cuda-cusparse-8-0 cuda-driver-dev-8-0 cuda-npp-8-0
  cuda-nvgraph-8-0 cuda-nvml-dev-8-0 cuda-nvrtc-8-0
11 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 184 not upgraded.
31 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/416 MB of archives.
After this operation, 871 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  cuda-cudart-8-0 cuda-driver-dev-8-0 cuda-nvrtc-8-0 cuda-cusolver-8-0
  cuda-cublas-8-0 cuda-cufft-8-0 cuda-curand-8-0 cuda-cusparse-8-0
  cuda-npp-8-0 cuda-nvml-dev-8-0 cuda-nvgraph-8-0
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/  cuda-cudart-8-0 8.0.61-1
  File not found
Err file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/  cuda-driver-dev-8-0 8.0.61-1
  File not found
Err file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/  cuda-nvrtc-8-0 8.0.61-1
  File not found
Err file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/  cuda-cusolver-8-0 8.0.61-1
  File not found
Err file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/  cuda-cublas-8-0 8.0.61-1
  File not found
Err file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/  cuda-cufft-8-0 8.0.61-1
  File not found
Err file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/  cuda-curand-8-0 8.0.61-1
  File not found
Err file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/  cuda-cusparse-8-0 8.0.61-1
  File not found
Err file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/  cuda-npp-8-0 8.0.61-1
  File not found
Err file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/  cuda-nvml-dev-8-0 8.0.61-1
  File not found
Err file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/  cuda-nvgraph-8-0 8.0.61-1
  File not found
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/./cuda-cudart-8-0_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb  File not found

E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/./cuda-driver-dev-8-0_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb  File not found

E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/./cuda-nvrtc-8-0_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb  File not found

E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/./cuda-cusolver-8-0_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb  File not found

E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/./cuda-cublas-8-0_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb  File not found

E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/./cuda-cufft-8-0_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb  File not found

E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/./cuda-curand-8-0_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb  File not found

E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/./cuda-cusparse-8-0_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb  File not found

E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/./cuda-npp-8-0_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb  File not found

E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/./cuda-nvml-dev-8-0_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb  File not found

E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/./cuda-nvgraph-8-0_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb  File not found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get -f install` as directed by the message?

Comment: @George, I added some detail of output of `sudo apt-get -f install`. After `sudo apt-get -f install`, I can't install python3-tk because it still outputs the same error.

Comment: Please what does "I installed CUDA with another methods" mean, what method did you use? Meanwhile run this `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` lets see it will fix it

Comment: @George, I installed it with `runfile` rather than `deb` file. The main point here I think there must be some methods detach cuda deb so that apt wouldn't report cuda issue.

Comment: You could run that last command and select `N` so it won't install the unauthenticated packages. But why use a `runfile`?

Comment: @George, `runfile` is another choice for installation of CUDA provided by NVIDIA. It's is easier.

Comment: Try other methods given and which works...

Comment: You installed it first via dpkg and then you tried installing it via apt-get. I think something went wrong with your last command of the first three. You should remove everything and only either install from a deb directly or use the recommended package manager.